# Including dependency in Short Code EXEC (Wordpress plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, shortcode

I'm new to PHP, so forgive me for any missteps.

I'm using a Wordpress plugin called [Short Code Exec](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/)

I am writing a pretty simple piece of code that is dependent on a specific PHP library (call it XYZ)

I notice that I need to use Composer to install this library

the library's docs say run

```
php composer.phar require blahblah/XYZ
```

But, how do I do this within this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't run composer within the plugin, you will need to either run it locally and upload the files it downloads/creates or run it on your server.

You will then include the autoload file like you would with a normal php project with in the plugin (ie.  `require '/vendor/autoload.php';`) and then you run the rest of your code and the classes will be autoloaded for you.

Comment: that was so simple I'm embarrassed.